# Compare corresponding elements of a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to perform a simple comparison between 2 lists. How do I compare one elements from list A to the corresponding element of list B?
Lets say I have 2 lists.

A = [100,100,100]

B = [100,120,95]

I want to compare lists A and B (A[1] with B[1], A[2] with B[2] and so on).

```
A = [100,100,100]
B = [100,120,95]

if A <= B:
    print("A is less than or equal to B")
else:
    print("A is not less than B")
```

I expect "A is not less than B" to be the output but it prints  "A is less than or equal to B" which is not correct. Please help!

Comment: The code you wrote is different from the example you have.

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to check if all elements in `A` are smaller or equal to the elements of the same index in `B`?

Comment: You are looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: When you compare lists, it compares them element-by-element.  The first two elements are equal. A's second element 100 is less than B's second element 120, so A in fact _is_ less than or equal to B.  Why did you expect a different result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Function `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) will generate for you pairs of elements:

```py
>>> print(list(zip(A, B)))
[(100, 100), (100, 120), (100, 95)]
```

Now you can run an easy pairwise comparison [using a list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#how-do-i-apply-a-method-to-a-sequence-of-objects):

```py
>>> [a > b for (a, b) in zip(A, B)]
[False, False, True]
```

Now you easily can check whether the comparison holds for every element:

```py
>>> all(a > b for (a, b) in zip(A, B))
False
```

I hope this helps.